# How do we access the sensitive variables in a jenkins plugin that is workflow compatible?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to take the jenkins [gradle plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gradle-plugin) and make it compatible with the new workflow job type. I've gotten it to the point where I can use something like this and it will run gradle pretty successfully:

```
step([$class: 'Gradle', 
           switches: "-PenableInstallerDistribution=true",
           tasks: 'build install',
           gradleName: '(Default)',
           useWrapper: true,
           makeExecutable: true,
           fromRootBuildScriptDir: true,
           useWorkspaceAsHome: true])
```

However, I had to make some sacrifices. I had to simply delete these lines:

```
Set<String> sensitiveVars = build.getSensitiveBuildVariables();
args.addKeyValuePairs("-D", fixParameters(build.getBuildVariables()), sensitiveVars);
```

I can't find any way to access the "sensitive variables" from the `Run` object that is supplied in place of the old `AbstractBuild` and popping passwords into the console output seems like a bad idea. (I believe that's what the code is trying to avoid doing; I didn't write the original.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no `Run.getSensitiveBuildVariables()`, though it is possible one is needed. Anyway this method is merely communicating to *other plugins* which variables might be considered secrets for various purposes; it is not responsible for making passwords included in the command line from `ProcStarter` be shown as `****` in the build log, which would be done using `ArgumentListBuilder.addMasked`.

The quick answer is that, pending newer APIs, you should just skip this block if not given an `AbstractBuild`.